# Printing from lists

Tags: python, list

I've got 3 different lists, all the data inside is coming from an external CSV file which works although how do I print each name with each number next to them

```
name = [] 
number1 = [] 
number2 = []
```

for example expected output is, although I'm unsure how I would do this

```
LOOP (12) as there is 12 names and numbers in each lsit
Test, 5, 20
```

Comment: Just for the sake of correctness: if your objects start as `[]`, they are probably `list`s and not arrays.

Comment: Where did you get stuck with this?

Comment: Read up on `zip` and `for` loops.

Comment: "print each name with a number" -- `enumerate`?

Comment: Not sure how to print each name with each numbers from the lists for example the first name is test and the first number 1 is 5 then the first number2 is 20, I want that all on one line for each one in the lists

Comment: If you read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you may see that is asks you to create a [mcve]. You should show your CSV data, how you read it into your lists, then your expected output. What does `Test, 5, 20` mean?

Comment: Test (THE NAME) i said that already, 5(number1), 20(number2), all of which is inside the list from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
name = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
number1 = [1,2,3]
number2 = [4,5,6]

k=0
for v in name:
    print(v + ", " + str(number1[k]) + ", " + str(number2[k]))
    k+=1
```

**EDIT**

As MSeifert mentioned in the comment bellow here is better solution with enumerate:

```
name = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
number1 = [1,2,3]
number2 = [4,5,6]

for k,v in enumerate(name):
    print(v + ", " + str(number1[k]) + ", " + str(number2[k]))
```

Comment: fortunatly there is `enumerate` and `zip` so one doesn't need to bother with an intermediate counter variable `k`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using zip:

```
for triplet in zip(name, number1, number2):
    print(", ".join(map(str, triplet)))
```

triplet is a 3-tuple `(a, b, c)` with the corresponding element from the 3 lists (in other words, they are zipped)